# how to modify server relative url in response

Tags: node.js, response

I use http.request a URL and put the response to a new response in Nodejs. But the response of the http request has some server relative url inside, for the links, resources etc.

how can I make the relative url becomes a full url, then I can display the entire content in nodejs response. Thanks.